# Quadratic Equations with the variable raised to a power higher than 2.

Tags: polynomials, quadratics

This is the problem in question -

Solve the equation $ a^2 - 8a + 12 = 0 $. Hence find the four values of $x$ which satisfy the equation $ (x^2 - x)^2 - 8(x^2 - x) + 12 = 0 $.

P.S. - I got the answers correctly (6,2: 3,-2 and -1,2) but the textbook i'm using doesn't explain the answers, so I want to make sure i used the right procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Factoring gives $ (a-2)(a-6) = 0 $, so $ a = x^2 - x \in \{ 2, 6 \} $. Solving $$ x^2 - x = 2 $$ gives $ (x+1)(x-2) = 0 \implies x \in \{ -1, 2 \} $.

Solving $$ x^2 - x = 6 $$ gives $ (x+2)(x-3) = 0 \implies x \in \{ -2, 3 \} $.

$\Box$

Comment: Thank you, that's actually how I got my answer. Do you know how I can format my fonts to whatever script this page is using? I'm tired of writing a^2 instead of a2.

Comment: You're welcome! Formatting is a matter of some dollar signs. It is called $\LaTeX$. You can read about $\LaTeX$ [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). As an example, I just edited your original post. You can see what I did there by clicked "edit".

Comment: @DanielOlowu - does the post answer your question?

Comment: Yes. Thank you.

Comment: @DanielOlowu You're welcome! The check mark below the arrows next to my post is the "accept" button which indicates that I answered your question.

Comment: For some reason i can't click it. I can't even upvote. It says i require '15 reputation'.

Comment: @DanielOlowu Ah, you should have it now.

Comment: Yes, i do. I'm so excited, though it's just 21.

Comment: @DanielOlowu Thanks for the accept! Glad to hear the wonders of the reputation system are striking. :)